# What causes this ClassNotFoundException in Android?

Tags: android

I don't understand what can be behind this exception. It was anonymously reported by one user of my app, I can't reproduce it.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{cz.fhejl.pubtran/cz.fhejl.pubtran.CustomMainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: cz.fhejl.pubtran.CustomMainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar:/data/app/cz.fhejl.pubtran-2.apk]
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: cz.fhejl.pubtran.CustomMainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar:/data/app/cz.fhejl.pubtran-2.apk]
at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
... 11 more
```

My AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="cz.fhejl.pubtran"
    android:versionCode="38"
    android:versionName="3.6"
    android:installLocation="auto">

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/appName"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Pubtran">
        <activity
            android:name="cz.fhejl.pubtran.CustomMainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="cz.fhejl.pubtran.MAIN_ACTIVITY" />
                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="cz.fhejl.pubtran.CustomResultsActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="cz.fhejl.pubtran.RESULTS_ACTIVITY" />
                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="cz.fhejl.pubtran.JourneyActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name="cz.fhejl.pubtran.PreferencesActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light"
            android:label="@string/settings" />
        <activity
            android:name="cz.fhejl.pubtran.MapActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name="cz.fhejl.pubtran.LanguageActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name="cz.fhejl.pubtran.FavouritesActivity" />
        <service
            android:name="cz.fhejl.pubtran.MapDownloaderService" />
        <uses-library
            android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    </application>

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="8" />

    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.location.network"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
        android:required="true" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: What type of phone, the vendor

Comment: Unfortunately the report doesn't include any other info besides the stack trace.

Comment: Post the code of your manifest please. Also it looks like your app uses Maps jar? - do they have Google Maps on their device (not all do)?.

Comment: Added my manifest. I don't know if the device has Google Maps but I think the installation should fail if they don't.

Answer (score 3):

Had this sort of problem today after upgrading to latest ADT/SDK. Also for me the exception was

```
Unable to instantiate activity
```

Took me quite a while. Checked that i used google-apis (for maps), uses-library, cleaned the project etc.

Deleting the .project and adding a fresh one (create new android project) finally solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Does CustomMainActivity subclass MapActivity? If so, this might be caused by running your app on an Android device that doesn't have the Google APIs (I haven't tested this), or is otherwise missing /system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar.

That should be fairly easy to test on the emulator - just create a AVD without Google APIs.

Phil Lello

Comment: CustomMainActivity doesn't subclass MapActivity, but I am using Google Maps in one of my activities. However, when the device doesn't have Google APIs, the installation should fail I think...

Comment: I'm stumped. How did this report come in? Was it automated? If you're not in contact with the reporter, and it isn't an automated report, then it may be the result of someone tampering with the app - a normal user won't see stack traces. Either way, without some contact with the reporter for a few more details (e.g. device, android version, google apps), I don't think you'll be able to go any further.

Comment: When any Android app crashes, the user has an option to anonymously send error report to the developer. This is a feature of Android OS.

Comment: @fhucho a feature of 2.0 and above I believe

Comment: This error can be reproduced by installing your app on a maps device. Then uninstalling google maps. But I don't know a work around to avoud the FC! :-(